# Does Ubuntu have an online code browser like http://sources.debian.net/?

Tags: packaging

Does Ubuntu have an online code browser like http://sources.debian.net/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no online code browser for all Ubuntu packages.

You can get information, source and binaries using

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

But for many packages you can get a link to online upstream code browsers.

E.g. search for `file-roller` package and you will get a link to

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/FileRoller

Ubuntu kernels have an online browser at

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/